# Get the eventhandler from a control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a page with items in a TreeView to open:

```
<TreeView Name="pxTreeView" IsEnabled="False" >
        <TreeViewItem Header="Static Model" FontWeight="Bold">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Structure" MouseLeftButtonUp="MenuItem_LayerStructure_Open_Click" IsEnabled="{Binding FieldStructureModelIsEnabled}">
```

I want to hold the TreeViewItem's header and event handler in a list.
Is there a way to 'get' the event handler from the TreeViewItem?

Like:

```
EventHandlerList events;
foreach (TreeViewItem item in treeview.items)
{
    events.AddHandler(item.Header,item.MouseLeftButtonUp)
}
```

But I can't retrieve the handlers delegate from the control.
Is this possible?

Comment: Nobody but `this` can do anything with an `event` but add or remove a handler. What is your purpose here? What are you doing with this stuff? There's bound to be another way to go about it.

Comment: I want to hold a list of the tree view items name and event so the user can search through the items and click the button.

Comment: But you're building the tree yourself in XAML? If I were you I'd build the tree by binding to a tree of objects it gets from the viewmodel. Give each object a property `public String Title { get; set; }` and an Action `public Action OnClick { get; set; }`. Write a generalized click handler for your treview items that calls `(((TreeViewItem)sender)DataContext).OnClick()`. If you want to present the list of Title/OnClick items to the user in other ways, do that in other ways, don't hide everything in a treeview and then go crazy trying to pry it loose again.

Comment: Given what I describe, you could display it in a ListBox, a ListView, a ContextMenu -- sky's the limit. Make the Action an ICommand instead and the ContextMenu is even easier.

Comment: Thank you Ed I'm going to use the Action implementation and am closing this question as too broad.

Comment: Not too broad, you were just thinking about it from the wrong end. Ping me if you run into any snags.